# Java: Is a Serialized stream tokenizable?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I have two classes, both of which implement the interface Serializable. I want to send objects of both these classes over a socket.

I understand that implementing Serialize for a class makes it objects converted to Byte Stream for storing in files or transferring over the internet.

My question is : is there any way I can tokenize the objects so it is easy to me to read the incoming ObjectStream at the server end ?

Tokenize as in :

Client end :

```
ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(obj1 + "," + obj2);
```

where obj1 and obj2 are objects of serializable classes.

Server end :

```
SomeTokenizer st = new SomeTokenizer(ObjectInputStream.readObject(), ",");
Class1 obj1 = st.nextToken();
Class2 obj2 = st.nextToken();
```

Thanks !

Comment: Why? Something wrong with `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` all of a sudden? Just write out the two objects *individually*, and then read them the same way.

Comment: ok ! However, I'm new here and I don't get why my question got a downvote ? @EJP

Comment: @yshavit No, they are not tokenisable, and saying they are is not 'putting it another way'. The OP's code will write a `String` consisting of `obj1.toString()+","+obj2.toString()`, and whether that is either tokenisable or indeed useful in any way remains entirely moot.

Comment: @EJP You're right, I should be more careful with throwing terms around by way of analogy when it can cause confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object stream is not tokenizable.  The data is encoded in binary.

---

What your code is actually doing (more or less) is to convert the objects into a comma separated string, and then send the string as an object stream serialization.  When you do this:

```
ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(obj1 + "," + obj2);
```

you are relying on the respective `toString()` methods for `obj1` and `obj2` to convert them into *decodable* strings.  If that worked, then the following could "work":

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(
    (String) ObjectInputStream.readObject(), ",");
String obj1AsString = st.nextToken();
String obj2AsString = st.nextToken();
```

The prerequisites are

1. you need to write custom `toString()` methods,
2. the `toString()` methods need to include all necessary information,
3. the `toString()` methods must not include commas to confound the tokenization.

However, you would *still* need to convert the strings back into objects.  That would require *more* custom code that can parse the format produced by your `toString` methods and reconstruct the objects.

---

This is all very wrong at a number of levels.

For the right way to do this, see @EJP's answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining in a clear way ! @StephenC

Answer (score 0):

Why? No tokenization necessary.

```
out.writeObject(obj1);
out.writeObject(obj2);
// ...
Class1 obj1 = in.readObject();
Class2 obj2 = in.readObject();
```